# I'm getting a syntax error where the colon is after "if (num < 0)"

Tags: python

```
num = float(input('Enter a positive number: ')
if (num < 0):
    print("Sorry, factorial does not exist for negative numbers") 
elif (num == 0):
    print("The factorial of 0 is 1.")
else:
   for i in range(1,num + 1):     
       factorial = factorial * i
   print("The factorial of",num,"is",factorial)
```

Comment: the indentation in the question shouldn't be fixed, it's the cause of the error!

Comment: There is a missing bracket at the first line.

Comment: And there's a _bracket overflow_ in the `if` line. `if num < 0:` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors here.

- There is a missing closing bracket on line one.
- Using an int would be more appropriate than a float.
- The variable factorial in line 8 is not initialised, but then
  references itself.
- The last line is not correctly formatted.

Please compare it with the following code which will work:

```
def factorial(x):
    if x == 1 or x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * factorial(x-1)

num = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
if (num < 0):
    print("Sorry, factorial does not exist for negative numbers") 
else:
   fac = factorial (num) 
   print("The factorial of " + str(num) + " is " + str(fac))
```

I have put the calculation of the factorial into a function which is recursively called (something you can study).